# ammo.js - Objects do not rotate?

Tags: javascript, bulletphysics, ammo.js

In ammo.js I am trying to make a creative type game - everything works as expected but when objects collide they do not rotate.

Code can be found here

http://blockhaven.uk.is/dev/BHJSP/

The example can be played if you just follow instructions from here

http://blockhaven.uk.is/dev

Not sure what the problem is - even if the rendering engine does not show rotation the blocks should still rotate when dropped on the corner of another right?

To be clear ammo.js is a port of Bullet Physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help anyone else I though I should answer my own question.

Make sure to set your mass to a non zero value! else everything will mess up.
The mass is defined here :

new Ammo.btRigidBodyConstructionInfo(***mass***, myMotionState, blockShape, localInertia)

Hope this helps :D